# Receiving push notification with a new page - Hybrid Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed an mobile app with push notification using IBM Worklight 6.1. I am mainly concentrating on Android and IOS. I can able to send and receive the push notification even when the app is closed. After receiving the push notification, when i am opening it, the app launching with the default page. Now my question is **Is there a way to launch a particular page when opening the received push notification using hybrid way?**

Comment: You will need to better define what do you mean by "another page"? Are you using jQM and have a multi-page app? What is your implementation type in regards to "page"?

Comment: Yes.I am using Jquery Mobile and i have multiple pages. Lets say, normally when starting the app the home page will appear. I have a separate page to display all the notifications. Now when i am receiving the notification when the app is closed. I will click on the notification which will open the app automatically. Now i need to show the notification page instead of Home Page.

Comment: Assuming you are following the PushNotifications sample project, you can add a changePage function inside pushNotificationReceived(). Have you tried that?

Comment: We can go to the notification page, when the app is running on foreground and background. But unable to move to next page if the app is not running on background.

Comment: See the answer that I have posted.

Comment: @IdanAdar, as I explained earlier I can navigate to the notification page when the app is in Background/Foreground. If the app activity is closed, onclick of received notification, the app home page is displayed. Instead, the notification page should be displayed.

Comment: So again, review my implementation in my answer. The app is *closed*. You tap a notification and the app then opens up. Upon receiving the notification you can decide how to handle it - move to another page or not. Test my implementation (in a new app not in yours) - see how it works, then implement it in yours. It does whaty ou want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for you to "change page" based on the received notification.
I describe one possible implementation to do so in my answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604731/1530814

You should review it and alter it for your needs.