# How to get data from notifications in hybrid app using Worklight and Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am writing hybrid application with IBM MobileFirst 8.5 and Cordova plugin and I don't know how to get data from Notifications.

I want to create a list containing data from notifications within my app. Is it possible using Cordova or IBM MobileFirst? I remember it is possible when I used e.g. Java on Android platform using handler.

All tutorials show only "how to push notification" from my app but I didn't find tutorial "how to get data from notification within my app".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such release "MobileFirst 8.5". There's either 6.3 or 7.0...

Additionally, you do not *send* notifications from your app, you only *receive* them in your app. All tutorials show you how to *handle* (display) notifications in your app. The sample apps that accompany the tutorials put the notification's payload (the text that was sent via the notification) in an alert - but you could just as well do anything else you'd like with it.

So for example, in the Hybrid sample app there is the following code:

```
// Handle received notification
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {
    alert("pushNotificationReceived invoked");
    alert("props :: " + JSON.stringify(props));
    alert("payload :: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
}
```

Instead of displaying the notification's `props` and `payload` in an alert simply [take the content and put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604219/creating-customized-push-notification-in-worklight) in a table...

Assuming you have a table in your index.html by now:

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Then in main.js find it and insert content into it:

```
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {
    $("#myTable").html(
     "<tr>" + JSON.stringify(payload) + " " + JSON.stringify(props) + "</tr>");
}
```

This is just a very simple abstract of what you could/should do in order to display the push contents inside a table upon handling it. You'll need to further enhance it.